# Removing a row in a concatenated dataframe with a continuous index and IDs

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, row

I have 2 dataframes I have concatenated together:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3],
    'Name': ['Car1', 'Car2', 'Car3'],
    'Number': [0,1,2]
    })

df2 = df1.copy()

df2['ID'] += len(df1)
df2['Number'] += len(df1)
final_df2 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

This creates a singular dataframe with the "IDs" and "Number" column correctly numbered from 1 to 6 and 0 to 5.  Now I need to remove the second Car1 from the dataframe and have the dataframe resume numbering correctly after I remove the row.  So results ideally would look like:

```
[ID    Name   Number]
[1     Car1      0  ]
[2     Car2      1  ]
[3     Car3      2  ]
[4     Car2      3  ]
[5     Car3      4  ]
```

Or what I think might be a better option is ignoring Car1 from the second dataframe altogether.  Is there a way to copy starting after the first row?

Comment: you can slice it `[1:]` like `concat([df1, df2[1:]], ...`.

Comment: probably in all situations you will have to assign new numbers `final_df2['Number'] = range(len(final_df2))` and `final_df2['ID'] = range(1, len(final_df2)+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can skip beginning (or ending) rows using slice like `[1:]`

```
final_df2 = pd.concat([df1, df1[1:]], ignore_index=True)
```

In all situations you will have to assign again all values for `Number` and `ID`

you can use `range()` (or `np.arange()`)

```
final_df2['Number'] = range(len(final_df2))
final_df2['ID'] = range(1, len(final_df2)+1)
```

or you can use `index` for this

```
final_df2['Number'] = final_df2.index
final_df2['ID'] = final_df2.index + 1
```

---

Full working example

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'Name': ['Car1', 'Car2', 'Car3'],
    'Number': [0, 1, 2]
})

final_df2 = pd.concat([df1, df1[1:]], ignore_index=True)

final_df2['Number'] = range(len(final_df2))
final_df2['ID'] = range(1, len(final_df2)+1)

#final_df2['Number'] = final_df2.index
#final_df2['ID'] = final_df2.index + 1

print(final_df2)

---
```